# SonarQube maven plugin - separating build and analysis in CI pipeline

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, sonarqube

I am setting up a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline for a Java 8 project and need to include a stage for SonarQube analysis.  The project is built using Maven.  Here is an abbreviated and anonymized version of the job I've defined in the pipeline so far:

```
sonarqube-check:
  stage: analyze
  image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
  variables:
    #
  script: 
    - mvn verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=myproject -Dsonar.java.source=1.8
  allow_failure: true
```

This fails, because the version of SonarQube we are using requires Java 11, and not all of the relevant jars for a Java 8 project are included by default.

According to the last comment on this thread: [sonar.java.jdkHome property does not solve](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonar-java-jdkhome-property-does-not-solve/88376/15), the `sonar` step depends on the compilation steps, but it should be possible to run the SonarQube analysis without the build phase, and instead rely on the build artifacts created in an earlier pipeline stage.

Is there a way to exclude the build phase from the maven command line, or somehow build with a different version of Java than is used to run the analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by passing artifacts between jobs and directly ask maven to run the Sonarqube plugin.

In abbreviated, something like that should do it :

```yaml
maven-verify:
  stage: build
  image: maven-jdk8-image # Use your jdk8 image
  script:
     - mvn verify
  artifacts:
    paths: 
      - target/
    expire_in: 1 hrs

sonarqube-check:
  stage: analyze
  image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
  script: 
      # Set the sonar.java.binaries properties and don't add maven step like verify
    - mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.10.0.2594:sonar -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true -Dsonar.java.binaries=target/classes -Dsonar.java.source=1.8
  allow_failure: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can archive artifacts and use them in later stages. The sonar stage does not need to use the same JDK version as the build stage, but it is important that the sonar stage is run in an appropriate JDK version compatible with your sonarQube version.

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dependencies
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts

Just run in the first stage the build command: `mvn verify`
And in the second stage `mvn sonar:sonar`

I personally like separating the build stage from the static analysis stage to better identify where the problems are coming from.

Be careful to save any files needed for static analysis. Besides the compiled code, you might need coverage reports or external issue reports.

And since you are making changes, I would recommend going directly to JDK17, since JDK11 is already deprecated for sonarQube 10.x on the scanner side.

https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/requirements/prerequisites-and-overview/#supported-platforms